# [tf] Sequence numbers of rostopic tf

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I noticed the folliowing weird thing: (don't be perturbed: for analysis I load it into excel.)

[image: image description]

Should the sequence numbers in tf topics published be increasing? I saw this and it was quite suspicious...

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/415668/%5Btf%5D-sequence-numbers-of-rostopic-tf/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2023-05-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

sequence numbers are deprecated and should be ignored.

The most in depth post about it: https://github.com/ros2/common_interfaces/issues/1#issuecomment-112621348

And removed in ROS 2: https://github.com/ros2/common_interfaces/pull/2

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2023-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2023-05-22**:
Thanks, @tfoote. As I have your briefest attention, let me pick your brain. I am struggling with a bug that I think relates to the tf of odom to base. In rviz, when I set the global frame to be odom, the /laserscan display gives an "unknown error". If I set the global frame to anything else, e.g. base, then it works fine. My current hypothsis is that while the tf tree looks fine, that something about converting the /scan message frame from scan to base to odom fails. Stumped.

Does any of that ring a bell?